# Dynamic validation error message in Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, validation, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I'm trying to validate that `instructions` in my `RecipeSchema` is a valid html string. For that I'm using a package called`html-validator`. I'd like to pass the error that such package returns as the validation error message, instead of a "static" message like `"HTML is not valid"`

My code:

```
const RecipeSchema = new Schema({
  instructions: {
    type: String,
    validate: {
      validator: instructions => {
        let isValid = false

        const options = {
          data: instructions,
          ignore: [
            'Error: Element “head” is missing a required instance of child element “title”.',
            'Error: Start tag seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected “<!DOCTYPE html>”.',
          ],
        }

        htmlValidator(options).then(data => {
          if (data === 'The document validates according to the specified schema(s).') {
            isValid = true
          } else {
            //  data is equal to the message I actually want to use
          }
        })

        return isValid
      },
      message: 'Oops, the provided HTML is not valid',  // this is static but shouldn't be!
    },
    required: 'Please enter some instructions for this recipe', 
  },
})
```

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use a callback as a second argument to your validator function.

From [an example](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators) of custom validation in the Mongoose documentation, you can pass two arguments to the validator function, the first argument is a boolean, whether validator succeeded and the second argument is an optional error message override:

```
validate: {
  isAsync: true, // to avoid deprecation warnings
  validator: (instructions, cb) => {  // callback as second argument
    let isValid = false

    const options = {
      data: instructions,
      ignore: [
        'Error: Element “head” is missing a required instance of child element “title”.',
        'Error: Start tag seen without seeing a doctype first. Expected “<!DOCTYPE html>”.',
       ],
     }

     htmlValidator(options).then(data => {
       if (data === 'The document validates according to the specified schema(s).') {
         isValid = true
       }
       cb(isValid, data) // data is equal to the message I actually want to use
     })

    // return isValid
  },
  message: 'Oops, the provided HTML is not valid', // default message
}
```

And I'm pretty sure you can try to make your code a little cleanner with the use of Promises instead of the callback.

Comment: I doubt promises will work for custom error message. Their documentation doesn't mention it (see http://mongoosejs.com/docs/validation.html#async-custom-validators), and mongoose would have to come up with a different scheme such as returning an object for returning the error message: 2 arguments (`isValid` and `message`) to a callback is fine, but 2 arguments for a resolving promise isnt.